# Bootstrap 1 extra px in chrome

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap for creating webpage.
I have derived body on two blocks(content and header). Inside the content block i have `div` with class `.container .sameTable` and inside it i have `div` with class `.row .sameRow` that  derived on two other blocks(`left` and `right`). `left` has class - `.col-xs-2`, `right` has class - `.col-xs-10` and both of them have class - `.sameCol` too.

In Opera, FF, IE i have no any problems. But in Chrome on different screen sizes, contents width has less then other blocks on ~1px. I read that i may be caused by percentage width defining, but i cant change bootstrap's classes. How can I avoid it?
image - http://c2n.me/3em6LU4.jpg

Additionally, if i removed `float:none` from left and right blocks, issue is wanised, but my left block became smaller then i need.
image - http://clip2net.com/clip/m421320/49445-clip-46kb.jpg

`.sameTable`, `.sameRow`, `.sameCol` it's my own classes that looks like:

```
.sameTable {
    display: table;
    padding: 0;
}

.sameRow {
    display: table-row;
}

.sameCol {
   float: none;
   display: table-cell;
   vertical-align: top;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a rounding problem with the Bootstrap grid. Since Chrome supports sub-pixel rendering, it will exhibit the bug. I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: @YenneInfo It's an answer. I'm aware it doesn't solve the problem but sometimes -- as in this case -- "no fix" is a valid answer.

Comment: I have tried to search by "Chrome disable sub pixel rendering" and etc., but it didn't get any results. May be somebody is able to get better info in that direction.

Comment: Its is another questions - "Why float disabling fix it and why top block are rendering ok, but bottom block have "bugs"?